Recursive sequence to a defined sequence
I want to convert this sequence to an exact sequence:
$\displaystyle u_{n+1}=\frac{\sqrt{u_n}+1}{2} : u_0=a$
I tried to make a helping sequence and study my sequence based on the helping one like:
$\displaystyle v_n=\sqrt{u_n}$
But I can't do it, I want a solution for this, and, how do you find the best helping function to study the given sequence? (Like a general rule for it)

Related.
